# Correcting #!/bin/env python shebang issue

Tags: bash, scripts, python

I recently installed DOCK3.7 on my workstation running Ubuntu 20.04. However, I encountered an issue where the python scripts called upon could not be located, despite specifying the correct path and ensuring proper permissions.

Upon investigation, I found that all affected scripts had a shebang line like this:

`#!/bin/env python`

To resolve this, I manually changed the shebang to:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

This resolved the issue. However, there are numerous scripts bundled with DOCK3.7 that exhibit this header problem. I'm curious if there's a more efficient method to correct this, rather than manually fixing each script's header. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If I do `$ env python` (and enter) , then that acts just the same as if I had typed `python`... what do you see, add the text to your posting. Also check `type -a env` or `which env`

Comment: Perhaps your system was upgraded without applying the `usrmerge` package (which would have made `/bin` point to the same place as `/usr/bin`)

Comment: ... for background see [What's the difference of using #!/usr/bin/env or #!/bin/env in shebang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706736/4440445)

Answer (score 0):

My `/bin` and `/usr/bin` directories point to the same place in Ubuntu:

```
$ ls -l /bin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Apr 11  2023 /bin -> usr/bin
```

Since yours don't, you could make a symbolic link from `/bin/env` to `/usr/bin/env`:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/env /bin/env
```

Or you could find and replace all the broken shebang lines using `sed` with `-i`. A link seems like the simpler and potentially least destructive solution though.

Comment: Nice catch! Thanks!